# T-SQL : need total time worked and volume produced from two tables

Tags: sql-server

Thanks in advance for any help.

I have two tables, `login` and `sales in`. I need to get total time worked from the login table and total volume sold form the sales table.

```
SELECT 
    L.AGENT,
    SUM (DATEDIFF(ss, LOGIN.LOGON,LOGIN.LOGOFF)/3600.0)AS TIME,
    SUM (SALES.SALEAMT) AS  TOTAL
FROM 
    SALES 
JOIN 
    LOGIN L ON L.AGENTID = SALES.AGENT
WHERE 
    SALES.START > '2015-09-29'
GROUP BY 
    AGENT
```

I expect it to return 1 column with the names of agents who worked on 9-29-15, 1 column with total hours worked on 9-29-15, and 1 column with volume sold on 9-29-2015. It is actually returning crazy high amounts for both of the summed columns (hundreds of hours and thousands of dollars).

Comment: Are there multiple records in the login table for a given agent? For example, different records for different days or "sessions". There doesn't appear to be any sort of date checks against that table which seems suspect. Unless that somehow is accounted for through the sales.start column. It's not really clear without more information on the schema.

Comment: Yes an agent may have more than one login and logout per day.

Comment: How does sales.start factor into all of this? Does checking sales.start somehow restrict the records that would come back from the login table? Without any restriction on the login dates, it appears that you're joining all of the login records for a given agent.

Comment: Awesome! I added  where l.logon> '2015-09-29' and now the volume is correct but the hours are still off. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the Cartesian product when joining tables. This should resolve problem.

```
SELECT x.AGENT,
    x.TIME,
    (SELECT SUM(SALES.SALEAMT) FROM SALES WHERE SALES.AGENT = x.AGENT AND SALES.START > '2015-09-29')
FROM
   (SELECT L.AGENT,
    SUM (DATEDIFF(ss, LOGIN.LOGON,LOGIN.LOGOFF)/3600.0)AS TIME,
    FROM SALES 
    WHERE LOGIN.LOGON > '2015-09-29'
    )
```

Comment: Thanks this got me close enough to figure it out.